# Is it safe to assume that if I make two calls to async_read, the second call will be processed only after the first is processed?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm sending some data over the network and each data piece has a header consisting of two things:

1. data type
2. length of the rest of the data piece.

I'm reading the data type into one variable, and the length into another, thus the two async_read calls.

I know I can chain the async_reads and everything should work fine, i.e. first read the message type, and when it's read, in its async_read handler, call async_read for the data length.

But what if I don't do such chaining and just do async_read( data type ); async_read( data length );. Will Boost process the second async_read() only after the first has completed?

async_reads are called on the same tcp socket and on the same io_service object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a safe assumption. `async_read()` is implemented as multiple calls to `async_read_some()`, so the reads can end up being interleaved.

Comment: What about `async_write`?

Comment: Looks like it's the same -- does multiple `async_write_some()` calls. Will have to queue writes then.